# R and Quarto do not generate headers inside for loop

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto

I am using RStudio.
I want to generate headers and plots inside a for loop. But it does not work.

My code should generate three headers. One for each region_value. But I only obtain the header for the first region value.

What is wrong in my code?

````
---
title: "Generate Headers"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Generate dataframe

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false

library(tidyverse)
region = c(replicate(100,"A"),replicate(100,"B"),replicate(100,"C"))
variable = c(replicate(50,"var_a"),replicate(50,"var_b"),replicate(50,"var_a"),replicate(50,"var_b"),replicate(50,"var_a"),replicate(50,"var_b"))
value = runif(300, min = 0, max = 100)
df = data.frame(region = region, variable = variable, value = value)
```

# Plots

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| results: asis

regions_values <- unique(df$region)
for (region_value in regions_values){
  cat("## ", region_value, "\n")
  dfplot <- df |> filter(region == region_value)
  p <- ggplot(dfplot, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() 
  print(p)
  cat("\n")
  
}

```
````

Answer (score 4):

In markdown you need a new line before your `##` line for it to be interpreted as a header. As the [syntax section](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#:%7E:text=You%20should%20also%20put%20blank,after%20a%20heading%20for%20compatibility.&text=...and%20after%20a%20heading,this%20might%20not%20look%20right.) of the Markdown Guide says,

> You should also put blank lines before and after a heading for compatibility.

Change the second block to:

```r
#| echo: false
#| results: asis

regions_values <- unique(df$region)
for (region_value in regions_values){
  cat("## ", region_value, "\n")
  dfplot <- df |> filter(region == region_value)
  p <- ggplot(dfplot, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() 
  print(p)
  cat("\n\n")
}
```

This will produce three headers:

[image]