# Quarto chunk output is misplaced from the header ll Rstudio-Quarto

Tags: r, markdown, quarto, flextable

I'm using quarto to generate a pdf,
All of my chunks consist of two object, flextable and an gglot, my chunks looks as follow:

## Header 1

### Header 2

```
#| layout-ncol: 2

flextable(db) %>%
        fontsize(size=5,part = "all") %>%
        theme_vanilla() %>%
        align(align = "center",part="all") %>%
  width(width = 18,unit="mm") %>% height(height = .8,unit="mm") %>% 
  padding(padding = 2,part="all") %>% 
  line_spacing(space = .5,part = "body") 

ggplot(db,aes(x=ymd,y=cons)) +
  geom_line(size=2.5,position = position_jitter(width = 1,seed=123),color="#06334B")+
  geom_point(color="#06334B",size=5)+  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90,size =22),plot.title = element_text(hjust=.5,size=35),strip.text.x = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_text(size=20),text = element_text(size=30))
```

### Header 3

```
#| layout-ncol: 2

flextable(db) %>%
        fontsize(size=5,part = "all") %>%
        theme_vanilla() %>%
        align(align = "center",part="all") %>%
  width(width = 18,unit="mm") %>% height(height = .8,unit="mm") %>% 
  padding(padding = 2,part="all") %>% 
  line_spacing(space = .5,part = "body") 

ggplot(db,aes(x=ymd,y=cons)) +
  geom_line(size=2.5,position = position_jitter(width = 1,seed=123),color="#06334B")+
  geom_point(color="#06334B",size=5)+  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90,size =22),plot.title = element_text(hjust=.5,size=35),strip.text.x = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_text(size=20),text = element_text(size=30))
```

### Header 4

```
#| layout-ncol: 2

flextable(db) %>%
        fontsize(size=5,part = "all") %>%
        theme_vanilla() %>%
        align(align = "center",part="all") %>%
  width(width = 18,unit="mm") %>% height(height = .8,unit="mm") %>% 
  padding(padding = 2,part="all") %>% 
  line_spacing(space = .5,part = "body") 

ggplot(db,aes(x=ymd,y=cons)) +
  geom_line(size=2.5,position = position_jitter(width = 1,seed=123),color="#06334B")+
  geom_point(color="#06334B",size=5)+  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90,size =22),plot.title = element_text(hjust=.5,size=35),strip.text.x = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_text(size=20),text = element_text(size=30))
```

The first chunk works perfectly, the output is properly showing after ##Header2, but for the next ones, all the following headers, ##Header3 ,..., ##Header n , are showing before all chunks outputs

A long time ago I had a similar problem using kable, and I'd fix it with kableExtra using "HOLD_position" argument, I'm wondering if exist something like that for flextable or if my problem is for different reason as was it for kable table.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example of a Quarto doc. From what you've posted it sounds like this might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78073272/r-and-quarto-do-not-generate-headers-inside-for-loop), i.e. you need to ensure there are new lines before each heading. But not entirely clear.

Comment: Hi @SamR, thank you for taking the time to replied, I recently update the question with you request.